# Pass a df and variable argument in a function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

How can I write a function with a df and variable argument, evaluating both? I read several posts and blog-posts from r-bloggers and I think I have some problem with the lazy-evaluation, but now I'm terribly confused.

This is my function:

```
    RAM_char_func <- function(dataset, char_var){

      a <- dataset[ , c("id", char_var)]

      b <- a[[id]][is.na(a[[char_var]]) %in% FALSE]

      c <- a[a[[id]] %in% b , ]

      c


}
```

I get this:

> **Warning**
>   Unknown or uninitialised column: 'char_var'.

This should give me a table (c) with two columns and based on the char_var n-amount lines. while the code works outside the function, I cannot manage to get it working inside the function. I also tried the tidyverse-idea with select and filter, but that doesnt work, too.

I'm using R 3.5.1 with Mac OS X (High Sierra, 10.13.6) and R Studio (latest version).

**dataframe**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10),
                          var_10 = c(101:110),
                          var_25 = c("a", "b", NA, "c", NA, "d", NA, "e", "f", NA),stringsAsFactors = F)
df
```

Code Outside of the function is:

```
a <- df[ , c("id", "v_25")]
a

b <- a$id[is.na(a$v_25) %in% FALSE]
b

c <- a[a$id %in% b , ]
c
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
select(id, var_25) %>%
filter(is.na(var_25) %in% FALSE)
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example and the error message. 
From what I see, you probable have to parse the variable id to the function, but it's hard so say without more information.

Comment: I did add a sample df - the original df contains about 220 variables, therefore I simplified it. thx

Comment: I have corrected you data creation for df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve your issue:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

remove.na <- function(data, col){
    symcol <- enquo(col)
    data %>% select(id, !!symcol) %>% filter(!is.na(!!symcol))
}

df %>% remove.na(var_25)
#   id var_25
# 1  1      a
# 2  2      b
# 3  4      c
# 4  6      d
# 5  8      e
# 6  9      f

all_equal(df %>% select(id, var_25) %>% filter(!is.na(var_25)), df %>% remove.na(var_25))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of "teach a man how to fish", you can use the `reprex` package to be sure you're running your buggy code in a clean environment, and the error will be very explicit (you can also just run the code in a new session as long as you don't have a messy Rprofile file) :

```
library(reprex)
reprex({
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10),
                 var_10 = c(101:110),
                 var_25 = c("a", "b", NA, "c", NA, "d", NA, "e", "f", NA),stringsAsFactors = F)


RAM_char_func <- function(dataset, char_var){

  a <- dataset[ , c("id", char_var)]

  b <- a[[id]][is.na(a[[char_var]]) %in% FALSE]

  c <- a[a[[id]] %in% b , ]

  c
}
RAM_char_func(df,"var_25")
})
```

If you use `Rstudio` it will show the output in the Viewer tab, and the error that I get is :

> > Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, : objet 'id' introuvable

(sorry for the french)

It tells you object `id` can't be found, then you can check why your code is trying to access an object named `id` and you'll find easily the mistake in the 2nd instruction of your function.

If finding the sinful line is hard for you, try running `traceback()` right after the error or call `debugonce(RAM_char_func)` then `RAM_char_func(df,"var_25")` and browse until you find the line which fails.

Comment: merci beaucoup - learning about the reprex-package will be one of my next tasks - but your intro was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

your function contained an error. `[[id]]` must be `[["id"]]`

```
RAM_char_func <- function(dataset, char_var){

    a <- dataset[ , c("id", char_var)]

    b <- a[["id"]][is.na(a[[char_var]]) %in% FALSE]

    c <- a[a[["id"]] %in% b , ]

    c
}
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10),
                          var_10 = c(101:110),
                          var_25 = c("a", "b", NA, "c", NA, "d", NA, "e", "f", NA),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

call your function:

```
RAM_char_func(dataset=df,char_var="var_25")

#  id var_25
#1  1      a
#2  2      b
#4  4      c
#6  6      d
#8  8      e
#9  9      f
```

Comment: yes - this works fine, too! thank you - you have no idea, how long I changed single characters in the base-R-version and didn't succeed - thank you!

Comment: If 1h of research does not help you. Come here and better ask a question. Often it's a minimal error that experienced R-programmers can see in a blink of an eye.